# returns an error 'null is not an object (evaluating 'imagepickermanager.showimagepicker')' while calling method onpress

Tags: react-native, react-native-image-picker

when i try to access the photos using react-native-image-picker it returns an error 'null is not an object(evaluating 'ImagePickerManager.showImagePicker')'.

i have tried linking the libraries deleting node modules and then again etc but none worked.

```
const ImagePicker = require("react-native-image-picker");

<TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => {
                        const options = {
                            title: "Select Profile Pic",
                            mediaType: "photo",
                            takePhotoButtonTitle: "Take a Photo",
                            maxWidth: 256,
                            maxHeight: 256,
                            allowsEditing: true,
                            noData: true
                        }
                    ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, response => {
                        if (response.uri){
                            this.setState({photo: response})
                        }

                        })


firebase.storage.ref().child(`chatImg/${this.state.photo.uri}`);
                    }}
                    style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}
                >
                    <View style={{ width: 15 }} />
                    <AutoHeightImage width={35} source= 
{require('../../resource/icon_attach.png')} />                    
                    <View style={{ width: 5 }} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

adding the RNImagePicker.xcodeproj manually to xcode solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a bug with the current version. I've experienced this, what I did was to uninstall the current version on the image-picker package, and installed the version `@1.1.0`:

> ```
> npm uninstall react-native-image-picker
>
> npm install react-native-image-picker@1.1.0 --save
>
> react-native link react-native-image-picker
>
> cd ios
>
> pod install
>
> cd ..
> ```

Stop your Packager or Bundler and re-run it again

> npm start --rest-cache

Answer (score 0):

Unistall the latest version
npm uninstall react-native-image-picker
Installed version 0.28.0
npm install react-native-image-picker@0.28.0 --save
react-native link react-native-image-picker